# negation of "Between every two distinct real numbers, there is a rational number"

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working my way through Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*, and I am puzzled by the solution to one of his exercises, Ex 1.2.8(a). Ex 1.2.8 asks the student to "Form the negation of each claim." The claim to be negated in part b is "Between every two distinct real numbers, there is a rational number." The solutions manual lists the answer as "There exist two distinct rational numbers with the property that every number in between them is irrational."

Can someone explain to me how the second statement is the negation of the first? I know of course that the first statement is true and the second false, but it is not obvious to me why the truth of the first statement implies the falsity of the second, or the converse. One must draw in some additional information about the properties of the reals and the rationals to prove these relations. As a trivial example, consider the same two statements applied to the set $\{e, 3, \pi\}$. For this set, both are false.

Thanks!

Comment: Your "trivial example" shows nothing related to the actual question, which seems to be  how to logically negate a statement. This has nothing to do with true, reality or whatever. Besides this, the statement you have to negate *is true* in the set of all real numbers.

Comment: Well, then, ignore the example if you don't like it. You're right, of course, that the point of the problem is to demonstrate how to logically negate a statement. Can you explain how "There exist two distinct rational numbers with the property that every number in between them is irrational." is the negation of "Between every two distinct real numbers, there is a rational number."?

Comment: "This [how to logically negate a statement] has nothing to do with true, reality or whatever." Logical negation is related to truth and falsity in this way: if B is the negation of A, then it is not possible for both A and B to be true, or for both A and B to be false.

Comment: Your last statement seems to show that you still don't know how to distinguish between logical, formal true/false statements and "actual" or reality ones.

Answer (score 4):

Negation with quantifiers can be tricky. The rule is that the negation of *for all* is *there exists* and vice versa.

You may find it helpful to think through a problem like this symbolically.
In logical notation, the statement to be proved is that
$$
\forall x,y\in\mathbb R\;\exists r\in\mathbb Q\,:\, (x< y\to x < r < y).
$$
To negate the statement, we use the fact that $\lnot\forall = \exists$ and $\lnot\exists = \forall$ (here $\lnot$ is the logical negation symbol). The negation of $p\to q$ is $p\land\lnot q$ (here $\land$ means *and*).

In summary, each of the following symbolic statements is equivalent to the negation of the one above:
\begin{gather*}
\lnot \forall x,y\in\mathbb R\;\exists r\in\mathbb Q\,:\, (x< y\to x < r < y)\\
\exists x,y\in\mathbb R\;\lnot\exists r\in\mathbb Q\,:\, (x< y\to x < r < y)\\
\exists x,y\in\mathbb R\;\forall r\in\mathbb Q\,:\, \lnot(x< y\to x < r < y)\\
\exists x,y\in\mathbb R\;\forall r\in\mathbb Q\,:\, x< y\land\lnot(x < r < y).
\end{gather*}
(So we've moved the $\lnot$ inside the scope of quantification, switching quantifiers as we go.)

In English, the negation means that there are two reals numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x<y$ such that no matter which $r\in\mathbb Q$ we choose, $r$ will not be between $x$ an $y$. In other words, there are two real numbers such that every number between them is irrational.

Comment: Yes, but how do you get from "there are two **real** numbers such that every number between them is irrational." to "There exist two distinct **rational** numbers with the property that every number in between them is irrational."?

Comment: Maybe other people can back me up on this, but I think the solution manual is incorrect. I, too, do not see how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Leon, you can try the following (I'm assuming you don't know connectives, predicates, quantifiers and stuff):

"It is **not** true that *for all* $\;P\;$ something $\;Q\;$ happens" $\;\equiv\;$ "There exists **some** $\;P\;$ such that something $\;Q\;$ does *not* happen" .

Now:

"It is **not** true that for all *pair of distinct real numbers* there exists *a rational number between them* $\;\equiv\;$ "There exists *one pair of distinct real numbers*  such that *there does not exist a rational number between them*" $\;\equiv\;$ "there exists a pair of distinct real numbers s.t. **every** number between them is *irrational*"

The last logical equivalence above, and also in the books text, assumes that we *already know* that every real number is either rational or irrational (i.e., there is no third possibility here).

Comment: Yes, but how do you get from "there exists a pair of distinct **real** numbers s.t. every number between them is irrational." to "There exist two distinct **rational** numbers with the property that every number in between them is irrational."?

Comment: @LeonAvery It is explained in the answer: under the assumption that **every real number** is either rational or irrational, if between two distinct real numbers there is **no** rational number at all, then what's the *logical* conclusion? That all the numbers between these two distinct real ones **must** be irrational...

Comment: "That all the numbers between these two distinct real ones must be irrational..." But what allows you to assume that those two real numbers, which have no rational numbers between them, are rational? The solutions manual says the answer is  "There exist two distinct **rational** numbers with the property that every number in between them is irrational.", not  "There exist two distinct **real** numbers with the property that every number in between them is irrational."

Comment: @LeonAvery I see: the "two **rational** numbers " part is what bothers you. Yes, that very part is uncalled for and most probably is a typo in that somution manuel.

Comment: Thank you for actually reading my question! It took you a while, but you got there eventually ;-)

Comment: @LeonAvery Oh, I read it alright from the beginning, yet **you didn't** remark what the *actual* problem was and I, and (also the other answerer) assumed you were having problems with the quantifiers and their negation...hopefully you'll learn how to properly ask in the future. :)